# Objective C: Serializing/Archiving issues

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, serialization, archive

I'm an Android dev who's recently started IOSing. In all my of my Android projects, I have an IO class that does the following:

```
public static Object load(String fname , Context cont)
{
    FileInputStream fis = cont.openFileInput(fname);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object loadedObject = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    fis.close();
    Father.print("Loaded from file "+fname+" successfully");
    return loadedObject;
}
```

and the equivalent for save. It works great, I can load and save instances from anything with it.

In Objective C, I'm using NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver. Archiving seems to work, but unarchiving causes this:

```
*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?
```

I'm using the following static methods:

```
+(BOOL)saveObject: (id<NSCoding>)obj forKey:(NSString*)key;
{
        NSKeyedArchiver *archiver;
        NSMutableData *bytes = [NSMutableData data];
        archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:bytes];
        [archiver encodeObject:obj forKey:key];
        [archiver finishEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Successfully saved object <%@> to %@", obj, key);
        return TRUE;
}
```

and

```
+(id)loadForKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSMutableData *bytes = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unrar = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:bytes];
    id result = [unrar decodeObjectForKey:key];
    [unrar finishDecoding];
    NSLog(@"Successfully loaded object <%@>", result);

    return result;
}
```

I'm calling them as such

```
[IVIO saveObject:thing forKey:@"thekey"];
Thing *miracle = [IVIO loadForKey:@"thekey"];
```

What's going on?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `+loadForKey:`

```
NSMutableData *bytes = [NSMutableData data];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unrar = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:bytes];
```

you're trying to read from an empty data object. Creating a mutable data object using `[NSMutableData data]` just gives you an object that contains nothing. You'll need to READ the data from somewhere. Likewise, in your `+saveObject:forKey:` you successfully archive the object, but you don't do anything with the resulting data object.

To fix, you'll want to write the data into a file or URL in your save method, and read it from a file or URL in your load method.

Comment: Ok, I think I see my misunderstanding. I mean to save the data to persistent storage, yet all this is doing is flattening data. Thank you. Without wanting to ask for too much, can you point me in the right direction for saving to hard memory?

Comment: @soBinary: That's entirely up to you. NSMutableData inherits methods for reading and writing, and NSFileHandle can read and write data. I'm sure there are other options as well.